# SQL Server group by second interval

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've a problem with time group interval.

I want group by 90 seconds with this :

```
datediff(second, '1990-1-1', date_creation)/90
```

But with this :

```
2015-02-23 08:34:30.033
2015-02-23 08:34:30.017
2015-02-23 08:34:30.000
2015-02-23 08:34:29.987
```

I have this :

```
8816983.0
8816983.0
8816983.0
8816982.9888888896
```

And group by dosen't work :(

How to make it work ?

Thanks :)

Edit 1 :
With Floor :
8816983
8816983
8816983
8816982

My entire query is :

```
select intcol4.codtou [CodeTour], min(b.id) MinID, max(b.id) MaxID
    from intcolbgia b
    inner join
            (select id, codtou
            from intcol004
            union
            select id, datyen
            from intcol004vs
            union
            select id, datyen
            from intcol004va
                    union
            select id, datyen
            from intcol004cdt
            union
            select id, datyen
            from intcol004cde) intcol4 on intcol4.id = b.id
    group by intcol4.codtou, datediff(second, '1990-1-1', date_creation) /90) tournees
```

Comment: Your code works and returns an integer as expected, perhaps you could post more of your code as there maybe an error in some other part of your code.

Comment: Please add some sample data along with what you have tried.  With what you have given us right now the best we can do is guess.

Answer (score 3):

As written, your code should work, because SQL Server does integer division.  However, you can be explicit and use `floor()`:

```
group by floor(datediff(second, '1990-01-01', date_creation)/90)
```

The behavior that you describe suggests that you are using a decimal value (of some sort) for "90" rather than an integer.

Comment: If you want the original time back in seconds since 1990-01-01, then multiply the `floor()` by 90.  There is no reason to do this for the `group by`.

Comment: I want group by same 90 seconds interval :(